# Links in WordPress page body do not work

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

I am a newbie coder, so I apologize if this is an easy fix.

I am currently working on creating a website using WordPress 4.7.3. using a custom theme that a co-worker and I made ourselves. It is being currently being hosted on a desktop server.

On many of the pages, there are hyperlinks to other pages in the site and files (mostly PDFs). However, while the links have all of the appearance of being active, they are not clickable.

The links are coded in the body of the pages. Here is a sample of how they are coded:

```
<a href="http://www.t-test.dev/person/">A.Person</a>
```

I have used a similar format when coding for the menu, which seems to be functioning properly.

Do you have any idea what may be the issue or where I can begin to look?

FYI: The theme only uses footer.php, header.php
index.php and a CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Can you send file where the anchor tags are located

Comment: I do not understand.

The links are formatted in the conventional [ <a href="https//www.webite.dev"> Words describing website </a>] format if that helps.

(I am not sure how to show the html coding on stackoverflow.)

Comment: Can you send me the code of the file where the hyper links are, or send the website if its online.

Comment: I will try. It is in the actual body of the wordpress page, not in any of the external files, so I will attempt to send you at least part of the text of one of the pages (i.e. the part with the code).

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nuko5q2cf4e081d/StackOverflowText.txt?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wordpress if you want to use the anchor tag, you need to call a function for the theme of Wordpress.

Normally you would have:

```
<a href="images/myimage.png"></a>
```

In WordPress you need to make a call to the theme folder first, and than you can go to your directories where images or files can be located.

```
a href="<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?> . '/images/myimage.png'); ?>
```

It's the same for stylesheets:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css"/>
```

For stylesheets and javascript it is the best to enqueue them in the functions.php. For more information: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: you can use *any* link address with an absolute filepath without all that. The example in the question HAS an absolute filepath.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your help. For some reason, there was an invisible image over the entire page. Once I was able to remove it, the website began to work again. I wish you the best!